# How to load test/stress test a video streaming application for mobile implemented using Opentok?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, load-testing, stress-testing, opentok

We have a requirement to test an interactive broadcast solution that would allow viewers to engage with a presenter through real time video and voice communication, the same will also be broadcast to a larger audience(100 users).The solution will be implemented using OPENTOK API (WEBRTC video streaming) and will be **available on Mobile only**

Is there a load/Stress/Performance testing tool that can handle this requirement and basically allow me to generate these 100 virtual users that can stream the interactive broadcast?

Answer (score 3):

To test WebRTC at scale, you can look at [testRTC](http://testrtc.com/)

It is a commercial service that enables you to write a script that then gets automated and scaled up to thousands of parallel users that interact with your service. The focus is WebRTC testing and monitoring, so problems around resource allocation, users synchronization and media metrics collection and analysis are solved for you.

Here's something we've written last year on how we've looked at scaling a Kurento server (https://testrtc.com/sessions-kurento-server/) - the same/similar can be applied to any WebRTC-based app.

Answer (score 2):

There is not such that public tool, but in the OpenTok testing team we have successfully tested up to 3000 streams (number of publishers x number of subscribers), so, as long as network and devices are fine, you should have no issue with 1 publisher and 100 subscribers. This can help you as well:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/live-interactive-video/

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [How we test WebRTC live video sessions for massive audiences](https://tokbox.com/blog/test-webrtc-sessions-massive-audiences/) article I can see 2 things:

1. [TokBox](https://tokbox.com/) seems to be carefully load-testing their Cloud API so if your service relies on TokBox Cloud - you should be good to go (or focus your load testing on your application backend)
2. If you still want to perform the load test you can go for their approach and use one of [SDKs](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/java/) in order to create sessions using your favourite programming language and load testing tool. If you don't have any idea regarding which tool to choose you can check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for an overview of the most popular and advanced free and open source load testing tools and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

To test high load for WebRTC based products, you may like to look at LM Tools. Its a commercial tool. You may refer https://lmtools.com/webrtc-load-testing.

If you know what messages are exchanged between browser / client and server (backend), then LM Tools is pretty easy to configure the test.

One of the key differences in LM Tools, it supports higher load as all the components are developed using C (linux OS), and are lghtweight. We have been simulating millions of WevRTC sessions with proper guidance.

Note - I am one of the developer for LM Tools.